# static_assert used in expression which is used in SFINAE context

Tags: c++, sfinae, static-assert

If I use `static_assert` inside a condition for SFINAE, compiler emits an error and stops.

```
template < int i>
class X
{
    static_assert( i != 4 );
    public:
        static constexpr bool value = true;
};

    template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if< T::value, void>::type Do(  )
{
    std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
}

    template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if< !T::value, void>::type Do( )
{
    std::cout << "two" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    Do<std::true_type>();
    Do<std::false_type>();

    // ###########
    Do<X<1>>();
    Do<X<4>>();
}
```

Is this the behavior we should expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this the behavior we should expect?

Yes. The static assertion is in the instantiation of `X`, and not in the immediate context of of the template function. So it's not going to be mere substitution failure, the program will be ill-formed. There is a (albeit non-normative) note that further supports this should be this way.

> **[temp.deduct]** (with note emphasized)
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#8) If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type
>   deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be
>   ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the
>   substituted arguments. [ Note: If no diagnostic is required, the
>   program is still ill-formed. Access checking is done as part of the
>   substitution process.  — end note ] Only invalid types and expressions
>   in the immediate context of the function type and its template
>   parameter types can result in a deduction failure. [ Note: **The
>   substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as
>   the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function
>   template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined
>   functions, etc. Such effects are not in the “immediate context” and
>   can result in the program being ill-formed**. — end note ]

In your particular case, making `X` SFINAE friendly is also fairly straight forward:

```
// No static assertion
static constexpr bool value = (i != 4);
```

Or even

```
template <int i>
struct X : std::bool_constant< i != 4 >{};
```

Comment: No problem to make it working, it was intended as understanding question for the language-lawyers ;) The new thing to me is the "immediate context" here. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add that accessing member `T::value` will cause the implicit instantiation, since simply writing `X<1>` won't cause instantiation.

Comment: @liliscent - You mean [[temp.inst\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#1)? It's relevant, but I'm not sure how important it is to the question itself.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, my last comment just wanted to emphasize that the instantiation is caused by `T::value`, not `X<1>` itself. Sometimes it will cause confusion.